# Which article to use in front of fBm?

Tags: article-writing

I kindly ask for your help in the matter of usage of articles. My question is the following.
I usually see no article in front of "Brownian motion", e.g. (introducing a process)

> B is Brownian motion

I assume this is the right way to say. Am I right? 
However, I saw multiple different articles in front of "fractional Brownian motion" and its shorthand "fBm". So is it correct to write:

> 1. M is a fBm
> 2. M is an fBm
> 3. M is the fBm
> 4. M is fBm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is acceptable to use "$B$ **is** Brownian Motion", since it is typically understood that you are referring to *the standard* Brownian motion process.  If you want to be more specific I have also seen "$B$ is **the** Brownian motion **process**" or "$B$ is **the standard** Brownian motion process".

Personally, my preference is to call the stochastic process $B(t)$ the *Wiener Process* instead of Brownian motion; Brownian motion is the *physical process* of particles in fluids that was observed by Robert Brown;  $B(t)$ is the *mathematical object* constructed by Norbert Wiener (and others) to *model* Brownian motion.  So I usually use the letter $W(t)$, and I would say "Let $W(t)$ be **the** Wiener Process".

With fractional Brownian motion, there is not a single standard fBm process (there is a parameter, $H$), so it would be more correct to say "Let $B_H(t)$ be **a** fBm with Hurst exponent $H$" or at first usage, "let $B_H(t)$ be a fractional Brownian motion (fBm) with Hurst exponent $H$".

Comment: I appreciate your opinion and share it. I also think of fBm as a class of processes thus justifying the usage of "a". What do you think about saying "an fBm"? I heard that this can be justified by the following: when we say "fBm" the first sound is vowel ("ef").

Comment: Yes, "an fBm" is acceptable.